# How to get data from 3 tables with same user id?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables like so

Table 1: UserInfo

```
user_id   userName
```

```
123       userOne
```

Table 2: Post

```
user_id   postContent
```

```
123       This is test message
```

Table 3: LikePost

```
user_id   likesPostId
```

```
123       This is test message
```

I would like to run a query to get total number of post likes, posts, and user information from those 3 tables.

I can do this for each one such as in Post table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Post WHERE Post.user_id = '123'
```

and `SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE UserInfo.user_id = '123'`

Is anyone have better solution in just 1 query? Thank you so much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT ui.userName,Count(p.*),
Count(lp.*) as TotalPostLikes
 FROM UserInfo ui 
INNER JOIN Post p on p.user_id=ui.user_id
INNER JOIN LikePost lp on lp.user_id=ui.user_id
WHERE ui.user_id = '123'
GROUP BY ui.userName
```

If you want to select Username, Post and Likes on post, try the following

```
 SELECT ui.userName,p.postContent as PostContent,
        (SELECT COUNT(lp.user_id) FROM LikePost lp 
    WHERE lp.user_id=ui.user_id) as Likes,

(SELECT COUNT(_p .user_id) FROM Post _p 
    WHERE _p .user_id=ui.user_id) as TotalPosts

     FROM UserInfo ui 
    INNER JOIN Post p on p.user_id=ui.user_id
    WHERE ui.user_id = '123'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this approach counts the product of posts and likes.

Comment: @O. Jones , Yes, if you need to select Username, Post of current User and Likes of current user the try 2nd query

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. I just tried your answer but it is missing number of post count

Comment: Updated for Number of Posts

Comment: Thanks for an updated but the code just return 1 for post and 1 for likes even thought I think there are more than just 1 for both.

Comment: NVM I think your code shows correct counts but instead of just 1 row which shows user info, like count, post count but it shows multiple rows with unique post content but same like count and post count amounts for each row. Any suggestions?

Comment: I remove inner join and p.post content and problem solved. I will do some more tests and let you know soon.

Comment: @KevinVuD Thats great.

Answer (score 1):

Use a structured query (with subqueries) something like this.

```
 SELECT u.user_id, u.userName, p.num postcount, l.num likecount
   FROM UserInfo u
   LEFT JOIN (
                 SELECT COUNT(*) num, 
                        user_id
                   FROM Post
                  GROUP BY user_id
        ) p ON u.user_id = p.user_id
   LEFT JOIN (
                 SELECT COUNT(*) num, 
                        user_id
                   FROM LikePost
                  GROUP BY user_id
        ) l ON u.user_id = l.user_id
```

What's going on here?  The two subqueries, for example

```
                 SELECT COUNT(*) num, 
                        user_id
                   FROM LikePost
                  GROUP BY user_id
```

each generate a virtual table with either zero or one row per user_id, showing a count for each user_id. You then join those virtual tables to your UserInfo table.

Use `LEFT JOIN` because ordinary innner `JOIN` will suppress users that lack either posts or likes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but where should I enter user Id such as:'123" or '333'

Comment: I also I test the code and get this error: unknown column user_id in field list

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it within one query using `leftjoin` on `Post` and `LikePost` like below

```
SELECT COUNT(*),User.userName FROM UserInfo as User
leftjoin  Post as Post on Post.user_id = User.user_id
leftjoin  LikePost as LikePost on LikePost.user_id = User.user_id      
where Post.user_id = 123
group by Post.user_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the code just return count(*) and user name. I hope it will show like count, post count column with user info as well.